# Отправка массива int ble устройству

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Есть массив данных {0xFE, 0x00, 0x11, 0x08}, который нужно отправить bluetooth устройству, но девайc принимает данные на запись только в виде byte[]. Как правильно нужно преобразовывать массив int в байтовый в данной ситуации?

Comment: А в чём проблема - в int занято более одного байта?

Comment: @MBo да, 0xFE это уже  254, а у byte максимум 127

Comment: @kalugin1912, byte может хранить диапазон с -128 по 127. Как вариант можете его сделать unsigned c помощью Byte.toUnsignedInt(byte value).

Comment: @kalugin1912   0xFE - один байт (с отрицательным значением)